# What did Chinatsu make?

Tags: yuru-yuri

In the first season on Episode 6, they play with oil clay, and the clay model that Chinatsu make was censored.

[image]

What exactly did she make? Are there any pictures without the censorship?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's likely a nod to how terrible of an artist she actually is.  That is, when she *tries* to be good.

Earlier in the same episode, she was reading off a picture book to the group.  At the very least, it freaked Yui and Kyouko out a *ton*.

[image: Image fro Yuru Yuri, Season 1, Ep. 6.]

The likely inference here is that her art sculpture is *so* bad, that censoring it is the only sane way to show it to the rest of the world.

Comment: It was pretty scary.

Comment: To clarify, she's horrible at any sort of creativity when she "tries", in the second season she makes cookies and a scarf for Yui, the tests ones which she put no effort into looked perfectly fine yet the ones she made for Yui which she put all her effort into making was just as horrible as all her art, also when she spills ink on one of Toshinou's Mirakurun pages she tries her best to fix it, ruining it in the process